# SocketCoder: Voice and Video chat samples simultaneously

Tags: wpf, silverlight, webcam, videochat

I am trying to run Voice and Video chat samples simultaneously using SocketCoder samples (http://silverlightvideochat.codeplex.com/).

However, after I start the webcam/video chat, when I start the voice chat sample, it says `mic device already in use`.

I am able to do voice chat without starting the video chat project.

Answer (score 3):

Copy the code from the `startcamera()` method and paste it in `StartRecording()` (reference to `socketcoader`).

Single Capture Source for both Audio And Video devices.